# CSS hover isn't working with <a> tag

Tags: html, css, hover

I'm trying to show div on  tag hove with css. for some reason it isn't working.

this is my code:

```
<style>
.div-to-display {
    background: yellow;
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    z-index: 10;
    width: 150px;
    min-height: 50px;
    color: black;
}
.det1 {
    color: blue;
}
.det1:hover > .div-to-display {
    display: block
}
</style>


<td>
    <a class='det1'>link</a>
    <div class='div-to-diplay'></div>
</td>
```

When I replace this:

```
.det1:hover > .div-to-display {
    display: block
}
```

with this:

```
td:hover > .div-to-display {
    display: block
}
```

It's working that way, but I need it to be with `<a>` tag.

any help? Thank you!

Comment: 1. typo in the second to last line 2. you are using the child selector for `.det1:hover > .div-to-display` when the div is not a child of `.det1`

Comment: and error on class name `<div class='div-to-siplay'></div>`

Comment: @JérômeTeisseire this is only on my question. in my code it's ok thx anyway.

Answer (score 5):

```
.det1:hover + .div-to-display {
    display: block
}
```

Will work as it selects the next adjacent element

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/the-30-css-selectors-you-must-memorize--net-16048

Comment: thx, but still nothing happen when I hovered the `<a>` tag. any other reason you could think of?

Comment: Perhaps you could create a JSfiddle and have you corrected the typos?

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code was ->'div-to-siplay' instead div-to-display

[Check](http://jsfiddle.net/NF62c/)

### Html

```
 <table>
     <tr>
        <td>
            <a class='det1'>link</a>
            <div class='div-to-display' id="id1" >Conternt</div>
          </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

### Css

```
.div-to-display {
    background: yellow;
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    z-index: 10;
    width: 150px;
    min-height: 50px;
    color: black;
}
.det1 {
    color: blue;
}
.det1:hover + .div-to-display {
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just have this as your CSS.

```
a:hover{
(put styles here)
}
```

Of course you can also use the pseudo elements:
`a:link` (default), `a:visited` (has been visited before), `a:focus` (has focus) and `a:active` (is currently being pressed by the mouse.)

You can use a child selector to make this apply only to a class/id of your choice.

Answer (score 0):

There you go:

```
<style>
.div-to-display {
    background: yellow;
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    z-index: 10;
    width: 150px;
    min-height: 50px;
    color: black;
}
.det1 {
    color: blue;
}
.det1:hover ~ .div-to-display {
    display: block !important;
}
</style>


<td>
    <a class='det1'>link</a>
    <div class='div-to-display'></div>
</td>
```

or a take closer look:

```
.det1:hover + .div-to-display {
    display: block !important;
}
```

The plus means `.det:hover` and immediatly after it `.div-to-display`